# make visible a public spreadsheet (anyone can read/write) in my drive directory with google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I would want to make visible in my drive directory a public (anyone can read/write) spreadsheet.
I can do it opening the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=[public_spreadsheet_id] with the browser. (The link brings me to google spreadsheet and make it visible in my drive for further edits/views)
Is it possible to do the same using Google Drive API or Google Sheets API simply giving fileid?.

Comment: I solved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141183/google-drive-api-add-shared-folder-to-my-files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this in the Google drive api using the 
[Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) method

In the request body set role to writer and type to anyone.  This should make the file public.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I have no problem at all in setting Permissions. I want to make visible a file that is public (anyone can read/write) in a specified user_id google drive.